# Website Content Shown on Moz but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, heroku, zurb-foundation

I have a [site](http://serendipitynow.herokuapp.com/) I'm working on using the Sinatra framework and I've uploaded it to Heroku. On Firefox, I'm able to see the page and all of it's contents but on Chrome the color for all text, borders, etc. is white. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it? Note that I'm also using Zurb foundation for the HTML framework and Sinatra for the backend.

Below is my CSS page.

```
/* LAYOUT */
/*========*/
.the-page {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px   rgba(0,0,0,.1),  -4px 0 2px  rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 2px  rgba(0,0,0,.1),  -4px 0 2px  rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 4px 0 2px  rgba(0,0,0,.1),  -4px 0 2px  rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* MISC */
/*======*/

.center {text-align: center;}

.brown {color: #653000;}

.green {color: #003218;}

a{color: #653000;}

a:hover {color: #003218;}

.size20 { font-size: 20px;}


/* Prevent MOZ border outline */
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}

/* FOOTER */
/* ====== */


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #653000;
}
.body-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -65px;
}
.footer, .push {
  height: 65px;
}

.footer {
  color: black;

}
```

Comment: It looks like problem isn't related only to Chrome, but to all WebKit (I see blank page on Safari 6 for iPad).

Comment: Thanks for addressing the fact that it doesn't work for any Webkit based browser. I was unsure whether or not that was the case.

Comment: It looks roughly the same as in Firefox and IE10PP here (Win 7, Chrome 26.0.1386.0 dev).

Comment: @OllyHodgson Yep, it works in Chrome Canary (but not in stable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested with Chrome 24 here and looked at the applied CSS rules in the Developer Tools. By removing the `row` class from the `<html>` tag, I was able to see your website in Chrome.

The following rule appears to be the source of at least some of your trouble.

```
.row:before,.row:after{content:" ";display:table}
```

Chrome doesn't like the `display:table` rule applied to the `<html>` tag at all.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I guess I will have to go into Foundation and change some of the source code because I see no other way to fix this. The funny thing is that I use Foundation on other sites and it works fine. I wonder if I should address this to Zurb on Github or Chrome?